# How do I apply a division operator on a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to add the division operator `/` to `String`, which takes an integer.

The operator should produce an array of strings. The size of the array is the given integer, and its elements are substrings of the original such that, when concatenated in order, produce the original string.

If the string length is not evenly divisible by the integer, some substrings should be (one character) longer than the others. No two strings should differ in length by more than one, and any longer ones should appear before any shorter ones.

Like this:

```
"This is a relatively long string" / 7
# => ["This ", "is a ", "relat", "ively", " lon", "g st", "ring"]
```

How can I start?

Comment: I recall there was a Rails method to do that or something similar, but I forgot the method name. I think it uses regex.

Comment: Please explain why there are strings of size 5 in that array.

Comment: @Aetherus there should be `num` strings in the array, each of equal length or length +/- 1 in some if there is a remainder.

Comment: What possible practical use would this serve?

Comment: I've offered a solution to the puzzle. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use recursion.

```
class String
  def /(n)
    return [self] if n==1
    m = (self.size.to_f/n).ceil
    [self[0...m]].concat(self[m..-1] / (n-1))
  end
end

str = "This would be a woefully short string had I not padded it out."

str / 7
  # => ["This woul", "d be a wo", "efully sh", "ort strin", "g had I n",
  #     "ot padded", " it out."] 


(str / 7).map(&:size)
  #=> [10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class String
  def /(num)
      n, rem = self.size.divmod(num)
      p = 0
      res = []
      rem.times{res << self[p..p+n]; p+=n+1} 
      (num-rem).times{res << self[p...p+n]; p+=n}
      res
  end
end

p "This is a relatively long string" / 7
```

---

```
["This ", "is a ", "relat", "ively", " lon", "g st", "ring"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
class String
  def /(n)
    chars.in_groups(n).map(&:join) 
  end
end

"This is a relatively long string" / 7
#=> ["This ", "is a ", "relat", "ively", " lon", "g st", "ring"]
```

[`in_groups`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups) is a Rails method that splits an array in *n* groups.

Comment: Best answer so far, imo. There seem to be many cool "pure-Ruby" method-in Rails that for some reason haven't been adopted by Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, kind of bulky but O(n) time.

Let me know if there are any edge cases it fails for:

```
class String
  def /(num)

    if num > self.length
      return [] # or whatever, since this is an edge case / can't be done
    end

    remainder = self.length % num
    result = []
    substr = ""

    i = 1
    while i <= self.length
      substr += self[i-1]

      if i % (self.length / num) == 0
        if remainder > 0
          substr += self[i]
          i += 1
          remainder -= 1
        end

        result << substr
        substr = ""
      end

      i += 1
    end

    result
  end
end
```

**Edit:** Refactored - replaced subarrays with substrings

Answer (score -2):

```
class String
  def /(num)
    partition_size = length / num
    if length % num == 0
      scan /.{#{partition_size}}/
    else
      scan /.{#{partition_size},#{partition_size + 1}}/
    end  
  end
end
```

Comment: Please give me the corner cases.

Comment: `"hellohello" / 4` splits it into 3 instead of 4